# Browser automatically changes Line-Height?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am trying to keep the line-height within a paragraph at 1.0. Here is the CSS Class I'm using:

```
.bottombarinfo{
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.0;}
```

This is where I'm using the CSS Class in the HTML code, its a Paragraph/Span:

```
    <p><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="HTC ONE" width="238" height="168" class="floatleft">
<span class="bottombarinfo">From its beautifully designed aluminum chasse to its fluid Android OS, the HTC one is spectacular, but is it the phone to go agains the Galaxy S4 and
Apple's iPhone 5?</span></p>
```

I tried putting the picture outside of the paragraph and deleting/changing the span, but all three major browsers, Firefox, chrome, and IE all space the text with a line-height close to 2.0. So what should I do to get the browsers to show a line-height of 1.0? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried that, and it doesn't work, thanks for the answer though!

Comment: Please post a simplified [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) of the issue

Comment: I don't know why, buy it works in jsfiddle but not in the browser.

Comment: Use a CSS reset like the Yahoo YUI CSS REST  `http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/yahoo-css-reset-yui-3/`

Comment: Pulling just your HTML and CSS into a new HTML document does not reproduce the issue. The line height is 1 in all browsers and displays I imagine how you wanted it to.

Comment: line-height: 1.0; wont work. try 100% or 120%?? also your image tag isnt closed

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a reset stylesheet to prevent the browsers default styles? they can be found on the web and downloaded for free. just be sure to put it as your first stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<p><img src="images/1.jpg" alt="HTC ONE" width="238" height="168" class="floatleft" />
<span class="bottombarinfo">From its beautifully designed aluminum chasse to its fluid Android OS, the HTC one is spectacular, but is it the phone to go agains the Galaxy S4 and
```

Apple's iPhone 5?

```
.bottombarinfo {
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 300%;
}
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/85nbh/1/)

play with it here and get it where you want it